# Smart Contract - How to Copy or Clone it?

Tags: blocks, bytecode, clone

All - Could someone tell me if it is possible to copy or obtain a smart contract code that has been proven to work on the blockchain in the past. I have a block number and the smart contract address, so how do I obtain the exact code and files used in that contract?
Thanks

Comment: I would first recommend to look if that contract has an open source repository with the contract code. This way you can inspect the source code and make sure what it is exactly programmed for.

Comment: Secondly, popular tools like Etherscan.io allows contract developers to post their contract's source code on the contract page. Check that as well.